# Collect stdout logs for a shell script that runs inside another shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have a shell script called `load_data.sh` that runs inside a shell script called `shell.sh`

The contents of `shell.sh`

```
xargs --max-procs 10 -n 1 sh load_data.sh < tables.txt
```

This shell script runs on 10 tables at the same time in the `tables.txt`

Now I want to collect the Full logs of the `load_data.sh` So I did

```
xargs --max-procs 10 -n 1 sh load_data.sh < tables.txt |& tee-a logs.txt
```

But I am getting a mix of all the logs. What I want is the logs should be `1st` table log then `2nd` table log and then `3rd` table logs and so on...

Is it possible to achieve that. If so how can I achieve that?

Comment: Cant you create **log files** with `load_data.sh` ? This will solve your problem I think.

Comment: Because you are running the processes in parallel the only way to separate the output is to create a separate log for each process and then concatenate them at completion.

Comment: @JohnC I am a bit new to shell scripting Could you please let me know how to do this

Comment: @suleiman I put the same logic in `load_data.sh` file but it gave all the logs in zigzag order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem by creating a separate logfile for each time your script is run.  To get the logfiles to be created in sequence you can use the 'nl' utility to number each line of input.

```
nl -n rz tables.txt | xargs -n 2 --max-procs 10 sh -c './load_data.sh "$1" > log-$0'
```

Will produced logfiles in sequence

```
log-001
log-002
log-003 
..
```

To turn that back into one file you can just use 'cat'

```
cat log* > result
```

Comment: How can we add a date directory at the end `> log-$0'` so that all the log files go to the directory of that particular date